# Should I disallow drupal path or alias by robots.txt?

Tags: views, 6, path-aliases

I have 2 languages enabled on my site English and Japanese.

Japanese is the default and English has prefix "en".

I want search engines to crawl one View page only in Japanese.

So I decided to use `Disallow: /en/my-view/*` in robots.txt but my-view has alias.

Should I use `Disallow: /en/my-view/*` or `Disallow: /en/alias-my-view/*` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add both paths, as both of them are accessible.

However, I recommend installing [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) plugin. It will permanently redirect your internal path to the alias (if any). This way you only have to add one path to your robots.txt.

Comment: Thanks. OK so if I use Global Redirect should I disallow just the alias path and don't need to do it for the Drupal path?

Comment: According to [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29789/http-303-redirection-and-robots-txt) answer, one disallow on the alias should be enough. However, you should definitely test this as I can't find any documentation on the issue.